# How to add Blank space at the End of the UI-GRID IN ANGULAR 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

We have a requirement where we need to add blank space at the end of ui grid. please check the image for more clarity :

[image]

Comment: You forgot the image

Comment: Image Link is added now

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the widths of all the columns so the total of them doesn't fill the container entirely. Then, through CSS, you can adjust that space. Here you have an example:

https://codepen.io/davidballester/pen/XejpJb

This is the columns definition:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
  name: 'id',
  width: "20%"
}, {
  name: 'name',
  width: "30%"
}, {
  name: 'age',
  displayName: 'Age (not focusable)',
  allowCellFocus: false,
  width: "15%"
}, {
  name: 'address.city',
  width: "20%"
}];
```

Then, the CSS tweaking:

```
.ui-grid-top-panel {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.ui-grid-header-cell {
  background: #ccc;
}

.ui-grid-viewport {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.ui-grid-header {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution....but our requirement is to have blank space at end of the horizontal scroll and number of columns in the grid may grow dynamically